# Would gravitons be massless particles associated to moduli fields in string theory?

Tags: string-theory, quantum-gravity, moduli

String theory does predict massless particles associated with moduli fields that haven't been observed. Would gravitons be one of these particles?

Comment: No, the graviton emerges as one of the modes of the string. The massless particles associated with the moduli fields are completely different.

Comment: Thank you! And would these particles exist in any possible universe in string theory's landscape?

Comment: If you believe in the string landscape then the moduli have discrete values and cannot vary continuously. That means there are no massless particles associated with the moduli fields. Any one universe in the landscape has a specific set of values for all the moduli. The graviton exists in all universes of course.

Comment: And would these values be different in all these universes?

Comment: I mean would these universes have diffeent values between them?

Comment: In the context of the string landscape each possible universe corresponds to a different set of values of the moduli, so by definition each universe is different. But I must emphasise how speculative all this is.

Comment: I understand, but would that mean that each universe has an unique set of values different from all the universes, and thus, each universe has an unique landscape of possible universes?

Comment: There is only one landscape, containing many universes and every universe has a fixed set of associated moduli fields defining it.

Comment: @Forsete: we seem to be talking at cross purposes. The landscape is the collection of all possible combinations of moduli. Any one universe has fixed values of the moduli, so any one universe cannot contain it's own landscape. The universes are points in the string landscape.

Comment: @JohnRennie what is it that causes the moduli fields to have specific, discrete values?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in string theory, but I believe those massless particles are all scalars (i.e. spin 0), and thus immediately not candidates for the graviton (which couples to the stress-energy tensor and so must be spin 2).

Comment: Thank you! And would these particles exist in any possible universe in string theory's landscape?